# Setting Page Titles With Switch Statment Not Working With Error Pages

Tags: php, switch-statement

In my header file I have a switch statement set up to set the page titles. I want to keep it all in the header for easy maintenance, instead of adding a page title variable to each page.

My site is setup with the pages separated into folders, so www.example.com/ and www.example.com/about/ and so on. I'm using the following code: (I'm currently building the site in a subfolder called "alt" hence the first case being alt not empty.)

```
<?php
  $base_url=basename(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
  $base_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");

  switch ($base_url) {
    case "alt": 
        switch ($base_page) {
            case "index": $title = "Home Page"; break; 
            case "400": $title = "400"; break;
            case "403": $title = "403"; break;
            case "404": $title = "404"; break;
            default: $title = "Error";
        }
    case "about": $title = "About Page"; break;
    default: $title = "Error";
  }
?>
```

But now I'm adding in error pages, like a 404 page and I'm not sure how to set page titles for them since they are all in the main folder with the main index page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The updated code is now correct. I needed to nest the switch statement and add a break after it.